# Is there anything like IQKeyboardManagerSwift to move UITextView up in Swift iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, skyfloatinglabeltextfield

I have implemented `IQKeyboardManagerSwift` to float `UITextField`, but for `UITextView` I am not sure how to do this. Is there any pod available for `UITextView` in Swift iOS?

I am looking for textview should not hide behind keyboard and textview should float above keyboard

My textview is in tableview cell.

I have added  `IQKeyboardManager.shared.enable = true`
in apdelegate

Comment: IQKeyboardManagerSwift works for both UITextField and UITextView.

Comment: @NajeeburRehman for me its working only for textfiled but not for textview. Do we need to specify anything more for textview?

Comment: No I don't think so. What's your view hierarchy for UITextView ? Try UITextView with the same hierarchy as UITextField in your UI.

Comment: @NajeeburRehman  my textview is in tableview cell and number of table cells are dynamic sometime 4 or 5

Comment: Try UITextField inplace of UITextView in tableViewCell and figure out if it works.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but i need multiline editable hence cant use textview

Comment: I just said that check if IQKeyboardManager works with UITextField in tableViewCell or not ?

Comment: @NajeeburRehman i check but that to not working :(

Comment: Have you enabled the IQKeyboardManager ?

Comment: Please double check that you have enabled the IQKeyboardManager in appDelegate and have not disabled the IQKeyboard for that specific class.

Comment: @SandeshSardar check my answer please.